Determine VBA reference library for an object, sub, or function
Multiple times I've run into an unfamiliar object/sub/function via an online example but I didn't know what VBA reference I needed to include to use it. Is there a way to search the VBA reference library (not active libraries via object browser) for an object/sub/function?
Examples:
Dim patternCheck As New RegExp       '1
Dim fso as New FileSystemObject      '2
Dim nodeVar As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement '3

These are part of the libraries:

Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Microsoft XML, v6.0

What is the best way for someone unfamiliar with these to find out which libraries to import?
Additionally, lets say my application only has "Microsoft XML, v3.0" listed, is there a way to update the Microsoft VBA libraries so I could use "Microsoft XML, v6.0"?

I found this resource which has most of the useful ones https://www.vbaplanet.com/libraries.php.
To update to the latest versions (assuming they are installed on your machine) I usually use late binding for my "release" versions of code - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/early-late-binding/
